# How to set PWM frequency below 1Hz on RPi?

Tags: rpi.gpio, pwm, pigpio

does anybody know how to generate a PWM with less than 1Hz of frequency on Raspberry Pi?
I'd like to generate a PWM with 0.1Hz if possible.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use software PWM?  Which language do you want to use?

Comment: I am doing it in python. I'd like to have consistent PWM pulses